# Convert Timer Interval in seconds and minutes

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I can get in textbox the timer1 interval but it is in milliseconds how to convert in seconds or in minutes?

Comment: divide it by 1000 or 60000...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);

var seconds = timeSpan.TotalSeconds;
var minutes = timeSpan.TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: i have change 5000 in timer1.interval insert textbox1.text = seconds.tostring(); and work! thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `TimeSpan` to do the work for you

[C# Convert Milliseconds, Seconds, Minutes](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-milliseconds-seconds-minutes)

Try

```
public string getFormattedTimeFromMilliSecond(double milliSecond)
    {

        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliSecond);

        string formatedTime = string.Format("{0:D2}H:{1:D2}M:{2:D2}S",
                                t.Hours,
                                t.Minutes,
                                t.Seconds);

        return formatedTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`TimeSpan Methods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336b7btb.aspx).

```
   public static double ConvertMillisecondsToSeconds(double milliseconds)
        {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds).TotalSeconds;
        }


    public static double ConvertMillisecondsToMinutes(double milliseconds)
        {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds).TotalMinutes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

milliseconds to seconds

```
seconds = myMillisecondValue /1000;
```

milliseconds to minutes

```
minutes = myMillisecondValue /60000;
```